# Please fix and change functions to class

Tags: python-3.x

Fix this...

I am making a text based game where you walk through a park and along a beach and along the way you come across obstacles impacting the environment to teach people about littering and its effects.  I have removed tiles 3-17 and was just wondering the best way to change functions into classes so they are more robust.

````
##Class
class Obstacle:
    def __init__(self, name, score, kills=None):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
        self.kills = kills

    def throw_away(self):
        global saved, killed, holding

        if self.kills is not None:
            if self.kills in saved:
                saved.remove(self.kills)  
            killed.append(self.kills)
        if self in holding:
            holding.remove(self) 

    def pick_up(self): #and just get points
        global saved, score, holding

        if self.kills is not None:
            saved.append(self.kills)
        score += self.score  #adds points to the score
        holding.append(self)  #adds the item to holding so they can use it later on.       


##Variables
#[item on path (problems), points for resolving problem, what problem impacts]
obstacles = [Obstacle("plastic bottle",10,"a dolphin"),  #this list needs to be after the class as the class defines the Obstacle
            Obstacle("pile of leaves",2,None),
            Obstacle("hobo",10,None),
            Obstacle("plastic bag",20,"two aqua turtles"),
            Obstacle("the gardeners lost secateurs",50,"a small child"),
            Obstacle("dog poo",15,"someones shoe"),
            Obstacle("nylon fishing line",20,"seal"),
            Obstacle("descarded fish and chips in paper",10,"five seagulls"),
            Obstacle("batteries",50,"a school of fish"),
            Obstacle("someone littering",50,"a whale")]

saved = ["You saved:","Nothing!"]  #list of wildlife saved.
killed = ["You killed:","Nothing!"]  #list of wildlife killed.
score = 0  #score is split into categories to tell you how well you did.
status = "still_going"  #changes to "GAMEOVER" to skip tiles if you do something bad.
holding = []  #list of items you are holding.
import time  #gets time for sleeps inbetween tiles and new groups of action
import random  #gets random for random number; oldMan, bossFight and chicken.
playAgain = ""  #will be changed to Y or N depending if user wants to play again. 


##Functions
#the tiles each have different surroundings and scenarios you have to pass while on that tile.
#tile1 plastic bottle.
def tile1 (obstacles):
    global saved, killed, score, holding, status  #make all variables global before each function so that they may be used within the functions.
    print(".... You come across a "+(obstacles[0].name)+"!") 
    while True:
        outcome = input("Would you like to pick up the "+(obstacles[0].name)+"?  yes(Y) or no(N).").upper()  #gives user the option wether they want to pick up a plastic bottle or not.
        if outcome in ('Y','N'):
            break
        else: print("That was not an option, Try Again.")
    if outcome == "N":  #if user does not want to pick up the plastic bottle they kill a dolphin.
        print("You leave the "+(obstacles[0].name)+" on the ground and continue on your journey.")
        obstacles[0].throw_away()
    elif outcome == "Y":  #if user picks up the plastic bottle they save a dolphin and get 10 points. 
        print("You continue on your journey with the "+(obstacles[0].name)+" in hand.")
        obstacles[0].pick_up()
print (holding)

#tile2 cat.
def tile2 (obstacles):
    global saved, killed, score, holding, status
    print("You are walking along the path when you come across a cat.")
    if (obstacles[0]) in holding:  #only asks the user if they are holding the plastic bottle
        while True:
            outcome = input("Would you like to throw the "+(obstacles[0].name)+" at the cat?  yes(Y) or no(N).").upper()
            if outcome in ('Y','N'):
                break
            else: print("That was not an option, Try Again.")        
        if outcome == "N":
            print("You leave the cat alone and continue on your journey.")
            while True:
                outcome2 = input("Would you like to leave the "+(obstacles[0].name)+" on the ground?  yes(Y) or no(N).").upper() #if the user doesnt throw the bottle at the cat they have the option to drop it on the ground.
                if outcome2 in ('Y','N'):
                    break
                else: print("That was not an option, Try Again.")            
            if outcome2 == "Y":
                print("You leave the "+(obstacles[0].name)+" on the ground and continue on your journey.")  #you drop the bottle on the ground and then...
                obstacles[0].throw_away()
            elif outcome2 == "N":
                print("You continue on your journey with the "+(obstacles[0].name)+" in hand.")
                score += obstacles[0].score #if you keep the bottle you gain points.
        elif outcome == "Y":
            print("""You throw the """+(obstacles[0].name)+""" at the cat which then attacks you so you run away.
No beach for you!   GAME OVER""")
            obstacles[0].throw_away()          
            status = "GAMEOVER" #if you throw the bottle at the cat the game ends.
    else:  #if you dont have the bottle you can stroke the cat.
        while True:
            outcome = input("Would you like to stroke the cat?  yes(Y) or no(N).").upper()
            if outcome in ('Y','N'):
                break
            else: print("That was not an option, Try Again.")        
        if outcome == "N":
            print("You leave the cat alone and continue on your journey.")
        elif outcome == "Y":
            print("You stroke the cat, it meows and you continue on your journey.")



#tile18 final destination.
def tile18 (obstacles):
    global saved, killed, score, holding, status
    status = "GAMEOVER"
    print("You arrive at the bench with a recycling bin conveniently beside it.") #you arrive at your destination.
    if len(holding) != 0:
        while True:
            outcome = input("Would you like to put all of the recycling in the recycling bin?  yes(Y) or no(N).").upper()  #you have the option to recycle all of the recycling you collected along your journey.
            if outcome in ('Y','N'):
                break
            else: print("That was not an option, Try Again.")        
        score += (23)
        if outcome == "Y":
            print("You put all of the recycling in the bin sit down and enjoy your lunch.  YOU WIN!") #if you put all the recycling in the rcycling bin you win and get points.
            score += (20)
        elif outcome == "N":
            print("You sit down and enjoy your lunch with your collection of recycling.") #if not you keep your recycling and have lunch also winning.
    elif len(holding) == 0:
        print("You sit down and enjoy your lunch.") #if you don't have any recycling you just finish the game.

#endStuff displays score what you saved and what you didn't.     
def endStuff (obstacles):
    global saved, killed, score, holding, status
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print("Your final score is:",score)     #gives final score
    if score < 125:
        print("     You suck")
    elif score < 250:
        print("     Alright")    #score is less than 25%, 50%, 75% and above 75% then one for 100% available points.
    elif score < 375:            #Rates you and then gives a comment (things in print statements).
        print("     Good")
    elif score < 500:
        print("     Amazing!")
    elif score >= 500:
        print("     :O  TOO GOOD!")  

    if len(saved) >= 3:   #If the legnth of saved or holding is greater than or equall to 3 meaning something has been added nothing is removed from the list. 
        if "Nothing!" in saved:
            saved.remove("Nothing!")
    if len(killed) >= 3:   
        if "Nothing!" in killed:
            killed.remove("Nothing!")
        if "Nothing!" in killed:
            killed.remove("Nothing!")  #need twice if drop everything tile15 as adds nothing from saved when extends saved list  

    print("")
    for items in saved:  #prints all the wildlife you saved.
        print(items)
    print("")
    for items in killed:  #prints all the wildlife you killed.
        print(items)    

tiles = [tile1,tile2,tile3,tile4,tile5,  #list of tiles needs to be after functions as functions define the tile names
        tile6,tile7,tile8,tile9,tile10,
        tile11,tile12,tile13,tile14,tile15,
        tile16,tile17,tile18]

##Main program
while status != "GAMEOVER":  #calls the senario function.
    senario (obstacles)
    print("")
    break

while playAgain != "N":  #the whole progran is in a while giving the user the option to play again.
    for i in range(18):
        while status != "GAMEOVER":  #functions to play the tiles and end stuff.
            exec("tile%d(obstacles)" % (i+1))
            print("")
            for item in holding:
                print (item.name)            
            break

    while status == "GAMEOVER":
        endStuff (obstacles)
        print("")
        break 
    saved = ["You saved:","Nothing!"]  #next 6 lines reset all variables.
    killed = ["You killed:","Nothing!"]
    score = 0
    status = "still_going"
    holding = []  
    playAgain = ""
    while True:
        playAgain = input("Would you like to play again?  yes(Y) or no(N).").upper()  #user inputs Y or N with N ending the program and Y starting over.
        if playAgain in ('Y','N'):
            break
        else: print("That was not an option, Try Again.")    
    print("") ```

Thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to start with the basics of classes. Below are a couple links to some useful articles (that I used when I started with Python).

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/class

https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming

Now, in addition, let me make a recommendation to help you on your way. I'll start with just the intro of your first function.

```py
##Functions
#the tiles each have different surroundings and scenarios you have to pass while on that tile.
#tile1 plastic bottle.
def tile1 (obstacles):
    global saved, killed, score, holding, status  #make all variables global before each function so that they may be used within the functions.
    print(".... You come across a "+(obstacles[0].name)+"!")
```

If you want to take that function and add it to a class as a method, you might consider something like this:

```py
class titles_class():

    def __init__(self):
         # Do any of the class setup that you need here.
         # Perhaps an initial score needs to be set? You could pass it as an input.

         # Note that you can set class-wide variables to initial values here
         self.saved = ["You saved:","Nothing!"]  #list of wildlife saved.
         self.killed = ["You killed:","Nothing!"]  #list of wildlife killed.
         self.status = "still_going"  #changes to "GAMEOVER" to skip tiles if you do something bad.
         self.holding = []  #list of items you are holding.

    # title1 - plastic bottle
    def plastic_bottle(self, obstacles):
        # Don't need to use `global` to access variables, they're now class variables.
        # Do what you need in this method using the class variables.
        self.status = "something new"
        self.killed.append("a new entry appended to the end of the list")
```

Hope that helps on the programming front!

Just a quick note too, we're here to help, but not to write your code. We've got enough of our own code to write! ;)  Be careful using words or phrases like "Fix this" that fires people up sometimes and can be counterproductive.

Best of luck!